# Static UILabel Created in IB Slow to Display

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uilabel

I have a Storyboard with a ViewController with a UILabel and some UIButtons within a UIView. The UILabel has some text it will display. The buttons are showing up just fine when I run the project, but there's a delay in displaying the UILabel (sometimes 5-10 seconds). At first I attributed it to a network request I was making on a separate thread I had created in viewDidLoad, but then I commented out everything in viewDidLoad except the call to super.viewDidLoad(), and it still does the same thing.

I've seen these delays before when updating the text of a UILabel programmatically, or when something is holding up the main thread, but I don't think this is the case here, as nothing else is happening in viewDidLoad (or any other methods).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time *anything* is "slow to display", you've got a threading problem. You are giving these commands on a background thread. You must not do that. All communication with the interface *must* be on the main thread.

Comment: You're totally right. I didn't think there was anything *not* using the main thread, but explicitly telling my call to `presentViewController` to happen on the main thread fixed it.